# How to enable my flashdrive while im in the BIOS Setup Utility

Tags: boot

Im trying to install Ubuntu 32bits on my ASUS Eee PC. I want to install it over Windows XP Home Edition, using my 8gb flashdrive. On my flashdrive I have Universal-USB-Installer 1.9.5.5 by pendrivelinux also on the drive I have Install Ubuntu with the Ubuntu logo. I have downloaded Ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386, it has the Power ISO logo in front of it.NOW with all that said. Everythings working until I get to my **BIOS Setup Utility** Im typing everything that is under the BOOT tab.

```
HARD DRIVE DISK  
1st Drive [HDD:PM-Hitachi HTS]  
2nd Drive [USB: MyFlashdrive DT]  
OPTIONS  
HDD:PM-Hitachi HTS 543216L9SA00 [Disabled]  
USB: MyFlashdrive DT [Disabled]  

BOOT DEVICE PRIORITY  
1st boot Device [HDD:PM-Hitachi HTS] Disabled  
2nd boot Device [Removable Dev.] Disabled  
3rd boot Device [ATAPI CD-ROM] Disabled   

BOOT SETTING CONFIGURATION   
Quiet Boot [enabled]   
On Board LAN Boot ROM  [Disabled]   
Boot Loader [enabled]
```

My question is how do I enable my flashdrive so I can boot up. HELP!
I also tried the Ubuntu CD Helper, I get a error message. Could not retrieve the installation files. For more info, see the log files.
I went thru the Uncheck Hidden files process, that didn't work either. PLEASE HELP
         I WANT MY UBUNTU

Answer (score 0):

Finally got my Ubuntu. All I did was went back to my bios,instead of booting from my harddrve 1st boot,I let it boot from my flashdrive 2nd boot. I changed the order. Changed flashdrive to 1st boot,then harddrive to 2nd boot. Thats all it took. It took me a long time but I got Ubuntu now.